# Email Template Custom Font

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, custom, template, font

Is there ***any*** way to add a custom font on an email template?

@import works on some email clients, but not on GMAIL for example, same as @font-face or any CSS approach I've taken.

I've also tried copy/paste Lobster (as a testing font) font on an email with letterhead, and it doesn't render Lobster correctly and falls back to some other font.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can include custom fonts in your emails, but you cannot guarantee how the recipient's browser renders it. Because you don't know how the browser will render you have two choices:

1. Use email safe fonts.
2. Use web fonts knowing that it will not render the same for all recipients.

You can read a pretty comprehensive article on the topic on [Adestra](http://www.adestra.com/what-need-know-using-fonts-in-email/).